# Difference Between minimum steel required in Slabs and Shear Walls

Tags: structural-engineering, concrete, reinforced-concrete

My question is very simple, I need to know why the minimum reinforcement for slabs is less than the minimum reinforcement required in Shear walls?

What are the criteria and reasons to set minimum steel reinforcement in the two structural elements. (if a code reference is needed plz refer to ACI and EC)